# Java thread join in for loop, unknown behavior in output

Tags: java, multithreading

Here is the code creating an array of threads, starting them, and then calling join on them:

```
public class JoinExample {

private static class CodeForThread implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + i);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread[] threads = new Thread[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        threads[i] = new Thread(new CodeForThread());
        threads[i].start();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
        threads[i].join();
    }
    System.out.println("All Done");
}

}
```

I know that join waits for a thread to die before moving on, and that the threads may be called out of order, but will still complete their task. The problem is I have so outliers in my output. Can someone please explain why something like this might happen:

```
Thread-60 0
Thread-60 1
Thread-60 2
Thread-60 3
Thread-60 4
Thread-97 0 //***
Thread-59 0
Thread-59 1
Thread-59 2
Thread-59 3
Thread-59 4
```

Is this because that was one of the threads that got scheduled to start before entering the join loop?

Comment: The rest of thread 97 output should be somewhere below. is it not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't abnormal behavior.  When calling Thread#join, the **main thread** simply **waits** for that specific thread to finish before continuing execution.  Because every thread has a separate stream of instructions, they will all execute in any given order, as you've seen by the random 'outliers'.